# Merge two Maps (Map<String, Map<String, Object>>) with duplicate keys

Tags: java, hashmap, guava, multimap

I have two ImmutableMaps from guava that I am trying to combine them where they can have duplicate keys;

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> map1 = new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Map<String, Object>>()
        .put("config", ImmutableMap.of(
                "key1", "value1",
                "key2", "value2"))
        .put("categoryapproval", ImmutableMap.of("reason_code", "listing_quality"))
        .build();

Map<String, Map<String, Object>> map2 = new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Map<String, Object>>()
        .put("config", ImmutableMap.of(
                "key1", "value3",
                "key4", "value4"))
        .build();
```

So, I can not use `putAll()` method because it throws DuplicateKeyException which is as expected. The output I am trying to get is like;

```
"config" --> "key1": {value1, value3},
             "key2": {value2},
             "key4": {value4}
```

Finally, I have also tried `MultiValueMap`, however, `MultiValueMap` keeps values as `List` where I need to iterate over. In `map1` I can get `value1` by `map1.get("config").get("key1")` where value1 can be any kind of object. I appreciate for any kind of help.

Comment: You are going to need something like this:  Map<String, Map<String, List<Object>>>, aren't you?

Comment: Most of the time yeah but that value may not be a List.

Comment: Well, in this case it must be.  A list with only one element, or a list with two or more elements.  This makes simple to handle it, because always there is a list with at least one element.

Comment: oh that is kinda true. I got your point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Guava's [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) and Java 8's [`Map.merge(K, V, BiFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```
Map<String, Multimap<String, Object>> merged = new HashMap<>();
BiFunction<Multimap<String, Object>, Multimap<String, Object>, Multimap<String, Object>> remappingFunction = (value1, value2) -> {
    Multimap<String, Object> multimap = HashMultimap.<String, Object>create();
    multimap.putAll(value1);
    multimap.putAll(value2);
    return multimap;
};
map1.forEach((key, value) -> merged.merge(key, Multimaps.forMap(value), remappingFunction));
map2.forEach((key, value) -> merged.merge(key, Multimaps.forMap(value), remappingFunction));
merged.get("config").get("key1");
```

If you are not using Java 8 then you'll need to manage the merging of multimaps in some other way but the idea is the same.

Comment: Thanks this is a nice solution! I need to learn a little bit more java 1.8 futures : )